# How call a function outside of .Mod file of Dynare? (using Command Prompt of MATLAB)

Tags: dynare

How we can call a function (for example `dynare_sensitivity();`) in command prompt of MATLAB not in `.Mod` file of Dynare? I can see function in Command Prompt but How can i use it?